# Android: having basic problems with sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am having some trouble implementing a sqlite database in my simple android application:

a user is displayed a list of animals in a Listview.Upon selecting an animal the user is brought to an activity "Animal",which will display a picture of the animal and give them options to

- view Animal Bio
- Back

All very simple so far, right?

I have working the database, which will populate the listView of animals.Database currently looks like

Table Animal-
   _ID,
   Name

Table Biography-
   _ID,
   Bio

This is where I would welcome any helpful advice on my problem, or on how to improve my implementation.

Currently populating the DB as follows

```
long populateDB(){      


    String[] animalName = {"Lion" "Zebra", "Tiger", "Gorilla",...};
    String[] animalBios = {"Found in the "...}

    ContentValues animalNameVals = new ContentValues();
    ContentValues animalBioVals = new ContentValues();

    long[] rowIds = new long[animalName.length];


    // Populate the animal table
    for(int i = 0; i < animalName.length; i++){
            animalNameVals.put(KEY_ANIMALNAME, animalName[i]);
            rowIds[i] = db.insert(ANIMAL_TABLE, null, animalNameVals);
        }

    // Populate the Bio table
    for(int j = 0; j < bios.length; j++){
        animalBioVals.put(KEY_BIO, bios[j]);
        rowIds[j] = db.insert(BIOS_TABLE, null, animalBioVals);
    }

    return rowIds[0];
}
```

And had planned on being able to tell database which animal on list was selected by passing extras with the intent, eg if position on listItemClick == 1, pass in tiger and retrieve tiger bio from db.

**Problems:**

Then on the Animal activity page is getExtra() == tiger, telling the activity that tiger was selected from the list and to load this bio from the DB..well, I cannot see an efficient method of implementation for this idea and am struggling to do so.

My second headache comes from adding the bio to the application from the Db.Originally I had a test bio hardcoded in a string, shown in a TextView.Is there a way to retrieve a string from a cursor and add it to the TextView id?I understand I will need some adapter, what I do not understand is why cant it be as simple as setResource(R.id.bio) = bio.

Thanks you for reading and any help is much appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First problem**: First of all, I'm not sure why you don't have the column `Bio` in the `Animal`-table? As no `Bio` would fit to any other animal than itself, you can safely do this. By doing this you can query the database upon selection and pass the entire object (including name of animal and bio) to the next Activity and use this to get your information. If this was somewhat unclear, let me know and I'll try to explain it better.

**Second problem**: You can get values from tables (there of also Strings) using a `Cursor`. To get the String you can do something like this where `cursor` is the Cursor with your result from the database:

```
 String bio;
// Move Cursor to its first element
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
     // Make sure the cursor is not null
    if(cursor != null) {
        bio = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Bio")));
    }
}
```

**Sidenote**: If I read the code correctly, it seems that you use `long` for ID's? The usual thing to go about ID's is `integers` as far as I know.

Comment: Hi pecka, you are right about bio sharing the same database as animal, I was originally going to try my hand at foreign key implementation but have decided to leave it for the time being. Thanks for the code it has proved helpful in what I am trying to achieve.